# implicit cast for smart pointer implementation

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, smart-pointers

I am trying to implement a smart pointer class for educational purpose. When class U is a base of class T i want to be able to do the following.

```
ptr<T> t;
ptr<U> u = t;
```

I am struggeling to implement this implicit cast, so could someone help me with this?

Comment: Give `ptr<T>` a sfinae'ed constructor from `ptr<U>` constrained on `is_base_of`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of using `std::is_base_of` to achieve this.

In `example.h`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Example {
public:
  template <
    typename T2,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, T2>::value>::type
  >
  Example (const Example<T2> &) {}

  Example () = default;
};
```

As expected, the following program compiles successfully:

```
#include <example.h>

class Foo {};
class Bar : public Foo {};

int main (int argc, char * argv []) {
  Example<Bar> bar;
  Example<Foo> foo = bar;
}
```

Class `Bar` is derived from class `Foo`, so an `Example<Foo>` can be initialized from an `Example<Bar>`.

Also as expected, the following program fails to compile:

```
#include <example.h>

class Foo {};
class Baz {};

int main (int argc, char * argv []) {
  Example<Baz> baz;
  Example<Foo> foo = baz;
}
```

Class `Baz` is unrelated to class `Foo`, so an `Example<Foo>` cannot be initialized from an `Example<Baz>`. Clang provides the following error message: `error: no viable conversion from 'Example<Baz>' to 'Example<Foo>'`.